# How can I show HTML-document (character alignment) in Java Swing component?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

How can I show HTML-document like this one

```
<html>
<body>
<span style="float: left;">left 1</span>
<span style="float: right;">right 1</span><br>
<span style="float: left;">left 2</span>
<span style="float: right;">right 2</span>
</body>
</html>
```

using someone Swing element?

In browser **it looks exactly like I need**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWeRq.jpg)

But in Java It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4MnE.jpg)

I'm using jTextPane:

```
jTextPane2.setText("<html>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<span style=\"float: left;\">left 1</span>\n" +
                    "<span style=\"float: right;\">right 1</span><br>\n" +
                    "<span style=\"float: left;\">left 2</span>\n" +
                    "<span style=\"float: right;\">right 2</span>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>");
```

The problem is that **I need to use the character alignment attributes**. Not the paragraph alignment attributes. Since the paragraph tags are separated by a space between them. But it should not be there.

I have solved this problem using table in HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td width='33%' align='left'>left 1</td>
    <td width='33%' align='center'>center 1</td>
    <td width='33%' align='right'>right 1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width='33%' align='left'>left 2</td>
    <td width='33%' align='center'>center 2</td>
    <td width='33%' align='right'>right 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Java:

```
jTextPane2.setText("<html>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<table width='100%'>\n" +
                    "  <tr>\n" +
                    "    <td width='33%' align='left'>left 1</td>\n" +
                    "   <td width='33%' align='center'>center 1</td>\n" +
                    "   <td width='33%' align='right'>right 1</td>\n" +
                    "  </tr>\n" +
                    "    <tr>\n" +
                    "    <td width='33%' align='left'>left 2</td>\n" +
                    "   <td width='33%' align='center'>center 2</td>\n" +
                    "   <td width='33%' align='right'>right 2</td>\n" +
                    "  </tr>\n" +
                    "</table>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>");
```

But maybe there are other more accurate way. Please tell me.

Comment: Swing supports HTML 3.5 and a small subset of CSS, so it might not be possible to achieve using `<span>`

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Swing supports HTML 3.5.."* 3.2, but yes - really, **really** old HTML. *"..so it might not be possible to achieve using `<span>`"* I suspect that if it works in a typical browser, it should work in a Swing component. AFAIR the 'alignment' options were enabled in the Swing HTML rendering API.  OP: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* look of the text pane content.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It could the fact that the OP is using a `JTextPane` over a `JEditorPane`, and I seem to remember having trouble with span and div and resorting to table, but that might have been so something like a `JLabel`, not a text component :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"I seem to remember having trouble with span and div and resorting to table"* Oh right there with you.  And I'm talking about HTML for web sites. I'd try for hours to get the effect I want with floating DIVs then .. screw it, I'll just use a table!